# implicit Akka system in Scala trait

Tags: scala, akka

How can I make my ActorSystem available in `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, this is the code im trying to get get working. It compile but i get a null pointer exception for the implicit system in [Tcp](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.1/scala/stream/stream-io.html).

> Why do I get a nullpointer exception and what can i change to get my
>   system into my trait services? Why does it compile?

```
trait ServiceA {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem
}

trait ServiceB {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem
  Tcp().outgo... // Code compile but i get nullpointer exception
}

object Main extends App with ServiceA with ServiceB {
  override implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("MySys")
}
```

Comment: Is that second trait trait ServiceB?

Comment: Yes fixed the typo.

Comment: Can you post the definition of TCP in trait B exactly where does it throw null pointer? and your code for Main from where it is invoked?

Comment: I think the problem is more general and not implementaion specific. I assume this is enogh of an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors of `SystemA` and `SystemB` (which uses `system`) are executed before constructor of `Main` which includes initialization of `system`. Use `implicit lazy val system = ...` in `Main` (it is allowed to implement an abstract `val` in this way) and this problem should be fixed.

Comment: Is this idiomatic Scala? I really like using traits.

Comment: I think you can also use an initializer block like `object Main extends App { override val system = ActorSystem("MySys") } with ServiceA with ServiceB {}` if you don't want to make the `val` lazy.

Comment: I get "lazy values may not be abstract" when I try to create an implicit lazy val actor system in a trait.

Comment: @ThomasLuechtefeld You only mark the implementation as `lazy`, not the abstract val. It could be useful to say that a `val` can _only_ be implemented as lazy, but it isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to answer 
by  @alexei_romanov .
What do you want to achieve by placing `Tcp...` call in a trait body without assigning it to `val` or `def`? It is now just an action which is executed at some moment during initialization of `Main`. It can leat to undefined behavior since it is an action on not yet initialized object.

Comment: Yes it was just a bad example, tried to write the minimal code to show my point

Comment: "It can leat to undefined behavior" No, it can't; this is perfectly well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the trait initialization order, and it is indeed unfortunate that the type system cannot defend against this.

One option to resolve this is to put the ActorSystem initialization into its own trait and make sure that one gets mixed in first, so:

```
trait ServiceA {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem
}

trait ServiceB {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem
  Tcp().outgo... // Code compile but i get nullpointer exception
}

trait ActorSystemInitialization {
  val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("MySys")
}

object Main extends App with ActorSystemInitialization with ServiceA with ServiceB {

}
```